# Twitter authentication/login issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I keep on getting this error from Twitter when I try to login on our app. This was happening since May 23, 2013.

> Whoa there! The request token for this page is invalid. It may have
>   already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to
>   the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was
>   probably just a mistake.

I also saw some users experiencing this issue in this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/17911)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing it out there. Have you tried resetting the keys in your application management page? Or recreate your access token? (Unless the "Reset keys" option does this also).

Comment: Isn't that kind of destructive? If you recreate your access tokens, wouldn't that prompt each user to authorize the app again? And invalidate oauth tokens of existing users in the app?

Comment: I was assuming that no one was able to log in. If so I don't see why making users reauthorize your app is a bigger issue than no one being able to log in. Looking back at the [link](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/17911) however, it looks like it may have been an issue on twitter's end and it's been taken care of.

Comment: It happens with some accounts. Still an issue as of today. Just tried